# How to work with a custom theme that someone else created before me? (details below)

Tags: menus, themes, wp-admin, child-theme, theme-customizer

A company hired me as a web designer. Their website was designed by a private company that created the WP website from scratch: they customized a theme, installed all the plugins needed back then, and the website is... okay. Now, the plan my bosses are using does not allow plugin installment.

Even the simplest things like changing a font makes the whole process a hell ride. I have to open the source code from a cPanel and edit some parts manually. But that is not right, it shouldn't be the only way to edit the website.

Can anyone tell me please what to do in such a situation? WP is supposed to make lives easier, but not in my case... I tried to contact the people who designed the website, and they asked me to talk to them after the New Year. I try to Google any tiny thing I need to change on the website, but all I get is frustration because most of the answers say: "Install a plugin called "..." and I cannot do that :(

Some things I need to change, which I cannot change are these (and the list is growing):

- add .js code to a page (a page doesn't even show me a panel where the < head > < / head > can be edited, I Googled it);
- change a font;
- change a menu design;
- connect the MailChimp...

All the best and Happy Holidays!

Comment: you can do all these customisation in the theme. read this : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/what-is-a-theme/#what-are-themes-made-of

Comment: It's not WordPress making your life hard, it's your development work-flow. If you have cPanel access, you should have access to create an SFTP account which will be easier than using the cPanel UI to upload. I suggest creating a child-theme https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ which inherits from the parent theme, then you can more safely override template files from the parent without creating a massive mess.

Comment: Thank you Adam and Kaperto for your advice!